# Avoiding framer-motion initial animations on mount

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

Please see [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-on-mount-pfedo).

I have a basic framer-motion animation where the height of a box is animated when toggled. However, I want the box to be shown by default, but when the page loads the initial animation is presented.

My question is, how do I avoid having an initial animation for a component if it should be shown on mount, but still maintain future enter and exit animations? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Bit old of a question, but just in case some people stumble upon this. if you are using an AnimatePresence you can use `initial={false}` on the `AnimatePresence` component. Like so,

```
<AnimatePresence initial={false}>
  {someCondition ? (
    <motion.h1 {...yourProps}>
      yooo
    </motion.h1>
  ) : null}
</AnimatePresence>
```

More info here:
https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/##suppressing-initial-animations

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is provided in the framer motion official docs:
specifiy the initial prop with the value as false

```
<motion.div
...
initial={false}
>

</motion.div>
```

https://www.framer.com/docs/animation/##enter-animations

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this kind of solution;

1- I took variants to inside of the component

2 - I created two states for opacity and height

3 - States are initially same as where you animate to. So basically nothing happens when you first render.

4 - With useEffect, you can swap the values with the actual initial values, so after first render, the animation works.

```
export const AnimatedFallback = ({ isVisible }) => {
  const [opacity, setOpacity] = useState(1);
  const [height, setHeight] = useState("200px");

  const variants = {
    initial: {
      opacity: opacity,
      height: height
    },
    enter: {
      opacity: 1,
      height: "200px",
      transition: { duration: 0.5 }
    },
    exit: {
      opacity: 0,
      height: 0,
      transition: { duration: 0.5 }
    }
  };

  useEffect(()=> {
    setHeight(0)
    setOpacity(0)
  }, [])

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {isVisible && (
        <motion.div
          animate="enter"
          className="fallback"
          exit="exit"
          initial="initial"
          variants={variants}
        >
          Suspense Fallback Component
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if it is the components first render by:

```
const firstRender = useRef(true);

useEffect(() => {
 if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false;
      return;
    }
});
```

If it is the first render of the component, don't pass the variants to the `motion.div`. In your example this would look like this:

```
const variants = {
  initial: {
    opacity: 0,
    height: 0
  },
  enter: {
    opacity: 1,
    height: "200px",
    transition: { duration: 0.5 }
  },
  exit: {
    opacity: 0,
    height: 0,
    transition: { duration: 0.5 }
  }
};

export const AnimatedFallback = ({ isVisible }) => {
  const firstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false;
      return;
    }
  });
  
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {isVisible && (
        <motion.div
          animate="enter"
          className="fallback"
          exit="exit"
          initial="initial"
          variants={firstRender.current ? {} : variants}
        >
          Suspense Fallback Component
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For me specifying `initial` property in `motion.div` helped

```
<motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0, height: 0}}>
...
</motion.div>
```